# “SELECT * FROM book WHERE year=wyear AND account >= waccount1 AND account <= waccount1”

Tags: mysql

For several days I've been struggling to display data from the table in DataSet. When I do not put a condition in the WHERE, it displays the complete table, but only the rows in the table that meet the condition are required. If there are suggestions for a quicker view. Thanks a lot.

```
myConnectionString = pwput;
MySqlConnectionconpara = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();
conpara.ConnectionString = myConnec DataSetionString;
try
{
    conpara.Open();
    if (conpara.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        string waccoun1 = wnalog1.ToString();
        string waccoun2 = wnalog2.ToString();
        stringnupita = "SELECT * FROM book WHERE year=wyear AND account >= 
        waccount1 AND account <= waccount1";
        MySqlCommandcmdnal = new   MySqlCommand(nupita,conpara); 
        MySqlCommand(nupita,conpara);cmdnal.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", 
        wyear);
        MySqlDataAdapte radda = new MySqlataAdapter(cmdnal);
        MySqlCommandBuildercbb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(adda);
        DataSet dsd = new DataSet();
        adda.Fill(dsd, "book");
        conpara.Close();
        if (dsd != null)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dsd;
            dataGridView1.DataMember = "book";
            Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial Unicode", 7);
            dataGridView1.Font = Font;
        {
```

Comment: The condition looks strange it can probably be simplified to `WHERE year=wyear AND account=waccount1` or you have a typo and it should be waccount2?

Comment: In `WHERE year=wyear` both `year` and `wyear` will be treated as fieldnames. You must insert variable's values (with proper quotes around) into SQL string instead of variable's names.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use parameters like so:

```
...

stringnupita = "SELECT * FROM book WHERE year=@year AND account >= 
        @waccount1 AND account <= @waccount2";
  MySqlCommand(nupita,conpara);cmdnal.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", 
        wyear);
  MySqlCommand(nupita,conpara);cmdnal.Parameters.AddWithValue("@waccount1", 
        waccount1);
MySqlCommand(nupita,conpara);cmdnal.Parameters.AddWithValue("@waccount2", 
            waccount2);
    ...
```